# Is this a good question? - How to have a single city, that exports future tech, without breaking the world economy

Tags: discussion

I'm trying to figure out how [Academy City](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Academy_City), which is a city with that demonstrates technology that is 20-30 years in the future, and that technology keeps increasing with time... (or is kept at that distance while behind the scenes tech keeps moving forward... and new tech is rolled out whenever it seems people Outside the City are catching up...)

I'm trying to figure out how to price the city's goods so tech companies can exist and keep the world from being dependent on Academy City's tech...:

Perhaps it's like Mass Effect, and Academy City just sells what is high-end Outside tech but just a bit better... Like that Asari group on Illium...

---

So my question would have been like:

> If a location can make better products that are better by percentage 'p', at speed 's' times the normal rate of a city, with exportation speed at worst a week (supersonic jets), and can make a y% better version of their product in time 't', where 't' is 3 months (Look at Armored Suit development speed of new versions...)... etc.

Answer (score 3):

I think we have accepted economies that are not existent, as long - and that is my guess - they're somewhat similar to real economies, such that answering these questions gives insights that have some sort of external validity.

See also

- [Would a question about an abnormality in a simulated economy be acceptable here?](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1314/would-a-question-about-an-abnormality-in-a-simulated-economy-be-acceptable-here)